# How do I make an input that stretches from 1em of the left edge to 1em of the right edge?

Tags: html, css

I want an input that is always the width of its parent div minus 2em and that starts 1em from the left and ends at 1em from the right. How do I do this?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

**NOT WORKING**

```
.myDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    display: block;
}
```

This always ends up too narrow.

Comment: What `position` did the parent have?

Comment: @DavidThomas parent is absolute and is `left: 0em; width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another div inside your parent div around the input, set the input to 100% width and that wrapper div to margin: 0 1em

http://jsfiddle.net/3g8khuus/

html

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <input id='your_input' type='text' />
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 1em;
}
#your_input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: why the extra wrapper? Adding padding to the parent should work just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/3g8khuus/1/

Comment: there may be something inside the parent that should not be padded, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
.myDiv {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, there's not enough support for me to rely on that. Android browser prior to 4.4 doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

You give the parent left and right padding of 1em and make the input width 100%.

Don't forget to use box-sizing border-box in case you wanted to give the input itself a bit of padding left and right.

Example: http://jsbin.com/datihuquzo/1/

Comment: Added a jsbin example.

Answer (score 0):

Pad the wrapper div from left and right by 1em and then set the width on the input to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/fdoLx261/.  For this to work `box-sizing` should be set to `border-box`.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type = "text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    padding: 5px 1em;
}

div > input[type = "text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's another version that does not require `border-box`: http://jsfiddle.net/0Ln6nrky/.  For this to work, the input's border is zeroed out and replaced with `outline`, which does not change the element's dimensions.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body > div {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

body > div > div {
    margin: 0 1em;        
}

div > input[type = "text"] {
    border: 0;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
}
```